# ruby mail error, EACCES

Tags: python, ruby, email

I tried to send mail (ruby gem installed. `gem install mail` ). Then, it was an error.
The connect(2) is EACCES. What does that mean?

In addition, I send mail to same destination (smtp.example.jp) in python, that's ok.

Do you know the cause?

ruby code:

```
# coding: utf-8

require 'net/smtp'

host = 'smtp.example.jp'
port = 25

smtp = Net::SMTP.new(host, port)
smtp.enable_starttls
smtp.start(
  'localhost', 
  'USER@example.jp', 
  'PASSWORD', 
  :login
  ) do |s|
  s.send_message "hoge", 'USER@example.jp', 'USER@example.jp'
end
smtp.finish
```

error message

```
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:541:in `initialize': Permission denied - connect(2) (Errno::EACCES)

from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:541:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:541:in `tcp_socket'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:551:in `block in do_start'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:66:in `timeout'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:550:in `do_start'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:520:in `start'
        from smtp4.rb:10:in `<main>'
```

ruby version

```
% ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24) [i386-mingw32]
```

python code. that's ok.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import smtplib

s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.example.jp', 25)
s.login('USER@example.jp', "PASSWORD")
s.sendmail('USER@example.jp', 'USER@example.jp', "hogehoge")
s.close()
```

python version

```
$ python --version
Python 2.5.1
```

Comment: are you sure need use this options `smtp.enable_starttls`?

Comment: hi.
I remove 'enable_starttls', but I have same problem. hmmm....

Comment: uhhhhh.... sorry. 'ruby.exe' is blocked by In-house firewall. Becky! (B2.exe in Japanese MUA) was not blocked, so copy 'ruby.exe' to 'B2.exe', then i can send mail :-(